# Why is this DialogFragment with custom layout blank?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to build a fullscreen dialog fragment but the layout is totally blank and I cannot figure out why.

This are my codes:

**fragment_tag_cat.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tagcat_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Blah Balh"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tagcat_number"
        android:text="Texr text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tagcat_header"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tagcat_recycler"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tagcat_number"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="500"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:id="@+id/tagcat_cancel_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**TagCatFragment**

```
public class TagCatFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private final String TAG = "TagCatFragment";
    private static final String SLUG = "slug";
    private static final String SOURCE = "source";
    private static final String NAME = "name";

    private String mSlug;
    private String mSource;
    private String mName;

    public TagCatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static TagCatFragment newInstance(String name, String slug, String source) {
        TagCatFragment fragment = new TagCatFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(SLUG, slug);
        args.putString(SOURCE, source);
        args.putString(NAME, name);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mSlug = getArguments().getString(SLUG);
            mSource = getArguments().getString(SOURCE);
            mName = getArguments().getString(NAME);

            Log.d(TAG, "Slug is " + mSlug + " and Source is " + mSource);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tag_cat, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceStare) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceStare);
        getDialog().setTitle("Showing posts taged" + mName);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog called");
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored");
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params) ;
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

   @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView");
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) {
            getDialog().setOnDismissListener(null);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
        getDialog().getWindow()
                .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.TagCatDialog;
    }
}
```

Please, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: First try to remove the code from `onResume` method

Comment: @AmanJain I tried it but no difference